# Integral with trigonometric function

Tags: integration

I have a problem with this integral

$$\int_\ \frac{\sin 2x }{  \sqrt{4-\cos^2 x}} \, dx$$

We can transform it to

$$\int_\ \frac{2\sin x \cos x }{  \sqrt{4-\cos^2 x}} \, dx$$

Using substitution $u^2 = 4 - \cos^2 x $ we get

$$\int_\ \frac{2u }{\ u } \, du$$

And it gives bad result. Can you point when did i make the mistake ?

Comment: Apart from a missing $2$, it looks good to me.  We have $2u\,du=2\sin x\cos x\,dx$.  So the integral is $2u+C$.

Comment: Yeah I forgot about this 2, but result from wolfram is very different. I added this 2.

Comment: The answer $2\sqrt{4-\cos^2(x)}+C$ is indeed correct!

Comment: It might differ from yours by a constant, which would be OK.

Comment: The derivative of $f(x)=2\sqrt{4-\cos^2x}$ is $f'(x)=2\frac{2\sin x\cos x}{2\sqrt{4-\cos^2x}}=\frac{\sin2x}{\sqrt{4-\cos^2x}}$, so your result is good.

Comment: Ok, but wolfram gives this as a result http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+sin(2x)%2Fsqrt(4-cos%5E2x). I don't know it why.

Comment: Why should one care about Alpha, a  commercial product?  Either (i)  it gives you in essence the correct answer that you got, or (ii)  it is wrong, in which case that's their problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result shown by WolframAlpha is
$$
\int\frac{\sin 2x}{\sqrt{4-\cos^2 x}} \, dx
=
\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{7-\cos2x}-\sqrt{7})+\text{constant}
$$
that can be rewritten, discarding additive constants,
$$
\sqrt{14-2\cos2x}=\sqrt{14-4\cos^2x+2}=
\sqrt{4(4-\cos^2x)}=2\sqrt{4-\cos^2x}
$$

This means you made no mistake at all.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I think WA is substituting $\cos^2x$ with $\cos2x$ and then doing another simple integral. The method used by the OP is sound.